# Unable to display a html file a blank screen appears

Tags: android, webview

I have a demo file in raw folder under res. When i click on a button to open the file a blank screen appears i am unable to resolve the problem.

Here's the code :

For the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

For the activity :

```
package com.ashsoft.basiccprogram;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;

  import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.webkit.WebView;

      public class First extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.first);


         WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
         webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
         webView.loadData(readTextFromResource(R.raw.demo), "text/html", "utf-8");
}


    private String readTextFromResource(int resourceID)
        {
            InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(resourceID);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int i;
        try
            {
          i = raw.read();
                while (i != -1)
            {
         i = raw.read();
                }
            raw.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
       {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return stream.toString();
        }

};
```

I am getting a blank screen. The demo.html is saved in the raw folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `demo.html` into your `assets` folder and use:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/demo.html");
```

Comment: Thanks . It worked ! 

Can we add adds on the webview  ?? For example can i use admob on the webview

Comment: @ashwinbhy You can't use admob itself in the WebView AFAIK, but you should be able to use AdSense. Or you could just put AdMob in your Activity.